# Is this an acceptable database design or not?

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I created 2 database designs (*External & Internal Database*). But I'm not sure if that fits in terms of relationship, normalization, logic, redundancy, ....

I also created 2 versions of the database design (*The first one without mapping table and the second with*). It's in German, I hope that's okay for you.

Do these designs meet typical relational database criteria such as 3NF, and do they specify the entity relationships in a clear and maintainable fashion?

[database design 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiqd5.png)

[database design 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSCG7.png)

Edit:
[current database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtqUz.png)

Comment: If you want to express the fact that a visitor could be registered as an attendee in >1 meeting, then M-ID does not belong in Besucher.  If the modeling language includes a notation for many-to-many relationships, then the connection is between the entities per se, and there is no need to mention any such thing as the attribute that will "realize" that relationship.

Comment: @ErwinSmout So I need to delete "M-ID" from table "Besucher" and connect them with the mapping table, right?

Comment: Thanks @qws, the English version is OK, there is no many to many relationships, and the tables is normalized. but the question is what is the required queries, this diagram (English) supports which visitor attend which meeting and the location of it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. As it stands, you're inviting opinions, rather than asking a question; that's considered off topic. Also - what's the difference between "internal database" and "external database"?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Okey, but it is still a question? I want to know if this database design is correct or not? The difference between "internal" and "external" is this: At first I add some informations (which I already know about my visitor) in the internal database. With a website the visitor can complete his datas in the external. With a job I will transfer the datas from the external to the internal database to get all the information about the visitor. Its just like a little safty for me to let all the data in the internal database und just get a few informations from the external database.

Comment: "Is it correct?" is technically a question, but it invites an opinion because you don't specify what "correct" means. At the very least, you should outline your business domain entities and the relationships between them. You might also specify whether you're optimizing for speed, size, maintainability etc. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @qws, I've edited your question to make it less subjective (and voted to reopen). Please check it still matches what you originally intended.

Comment: You don't give a specification, so no one can tell you if this design is appropriate. Questions like this right now are too broad, unclear, opinion-based & lacking research effort. If this gave a specification a justified answer would still be a textbook with a bespoke tutorial--same problems. Give just enough specification & design necessary to ask about the first place you are stuck. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS "3NF" means something--not "good design"--yet you say nothing relevant to it & show no effort towards addressing it yourself.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple of comments about the diagram linked as "current database design":

1. The **BM_Mapping** table should use **M-ID** as its foreign key rather than **Meeting_ID**. The current design prevents any change to a value in the column **Meeting.Meeting_ID**.
2. I would keep the same primary-key naming convention in the **Visitor** table as used in the other tables. So **V-ID** rather than **Visitor_ID**

Apart from these comments, the rest of the design meets the standard RDBMS [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_3NF) and entity relationship standards.

Comment: IMHO, I would recommend adding a new primary key **BM_ID** to **BM_Mapping** table and left the other fields **M-ID/Meeting_ID** and **Vsitor_ID** as foreign keys because this simplify the searching and joining in the programing language code later on..

Comment: @Ibrahim, adding a surrogate primary key (BM-ID) to the BM_Mapping table would indeed be important if you need to use that as a foreign key in another table.

Answer (score 1):

The ER diagram is OK of both internal and external because it is normalized, no redundancy, no many to many relationships and there is no functional dependency between fields except on the key.

Comment: @qws, Besides, are you aware that you need a synchronization scenario between both databases to keep them up to date?

Comment: Yes I want to transfer datas from the external database to the internal database (update them).